# Change string, sort backwards

Tags: php

I'm new with php and google is my best friend everytime but right now I'm kind of stuck.

So I have a form that is submitting to a php file, then the php files sends the form data to my email.

```
<?php
$year = $_POST['year'];
```

and the form submits '2020'
but I want the php file to change the order to '0202' like spelled backwards.

Comment: Has Google not told you about [`strrev()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Use [strrev](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php):

```
$year = strrev($_POST['year']);
```

Comment: That should have been a comment.